# Jackson ObjectMapper only interfaces known

Tags: java, spring, jackson, objectmapper

If I want to read some JSON into an object, and I have the interface but must use the Spring context to get the implementation class, I need to use a SimpleAbstractTypeResolver to map the interface to the implementation. So far, so good, if I know in advance what interfaces go to what implementation. But if the interface has methods that return other interfaces--and possibly down the line recursively--and I don't necessarily know in advance, I thought I could use reflection to figure it out. So this is what I came up with, but the compiler does NOT like the line **resolver.addMapping(method.getReturnType(), method.getReturnType());**, says it's not applicable for these arguments. I'm pretty sure the types are okay for that method--any thoughts on how to make this happen?

```
        for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
        if (method.getReturnType().isInterface() && method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
            // getter method returns an interface so find its implementation class
            Class beanClass = context.getBean(method.getReturnType()).getClass();
            if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(beanClass)) {
                resolver.addMapping(method.getReturnType(), method.getReturnType());
                mapInterfaces(objectMapper, clazz, resolver);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That fixed it. Dunno how I failed to noticeI was passing the interface in as both parameters. Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to review your types.

My guess is following:

```
resolver.addMapping(method.getReturnType(), beanClass);
```

(replace second parameter method.getReturnType() with beanClass)

or as an alternative (the code is not completely clear for me, sorry)

```
resolver.addMapping(clazz, beanClass);
```

You should put an Interface and Implementation into addMapping().

Example:

```
interface ITest{};

class TestImpl implements ITest {}

usage:
resolver.addMapping(ITest.class, TestImpl.class);
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably you need to review your types.

My guess is following:

```
new ObjectMapper().writerFor(<Interface>.class).writeValuesAsArray(<Class>);
```